# How to solve java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY007545: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader for media type

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-rest-client

I'm using Quarkus version 1.5.1, however when trying to send data of type LocalDate (or Date) of a form, it returns the following error message:

java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY007545: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader for media type: text / plain; charset = us-ascii and class type java.time.LocalDate

I have already imported the following dependencies, but the error persists.

```xml
<dependency>
<groupId> io.quarkus </groupId>
<artifactId> quarkus-resteasy </artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId> io.quarkus </groupId>
<artifactId> quarkus-resteasy-jsonb </artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId> io.quarkus </groupId>
    <artifactId> quarkus-resteasy-jaxb </artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId> io.quarkus </groupId>
<artifactId> quarkus-resteasy-jackson </artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Here is the code:

- Controller

```
@POST
    @Consumes (MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Transactional
    @Path ("/ new")
    public Response addSessao (@MultipartForm @Valid Sessao sessao) {
    
    sessionService.insert (session);

    return Response.seeOther (URI.create ("/ sessions")). build ();
    }
```

- Entity

```
@Column (name = "data_inicio_sessao")
@FormParam ("data_inicio_sessao")
public LocalDate dataInicioSessao;

@Column (name = "data_fim_sessao")
@FormParam ("data_fim_sessao")
public LocalDate dataFimSessao;
```

Comment: Does anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: How are you posting the data? The fact the error message mentions content-type text/plain is rather suspicious, and suggests you are posting data with the wrong content-type.

Comment: Thanks for the return Mark Rotteveel.
I didn't understand your question very well.
I am trying to send the data by POST via form.
The other forms are saving the data correctly, so much so that I know I change the type of this field to "String" it works and saves in the database.

Comment: My Head Form 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a correct answer to this exact post at: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10466#issuecomment-655922793. (txs!  marcelorubim).

On the other hand, I am using RestEasy and it works too.